# How does string multiplication work in Python?

Tags: python

What is the difference between these expressions?

```
>>> n = 2
>>> 'a'*2 is 'a'*n
False
>>> 'a'*2 is 'a'*2
True
```

Comment: Read `help('is')`: The operators "is" and "is not" test for an object’s identity: "x is
y" is true if and only if *x* and *y* are the same object.  An
Object’s identity is determined using the "id()" function.  "x is not
y" yields the inverse truth value.

Comment: The above is slightly different in that you did not explicitly use `==` but it's the same point of confusion.  It has nothing to do with string multiplication in this case.  The second case might work for a number of reasons (e.g. constant folding optimization)

Comment: @Iguananaut, yes, python optimization mechanism, I think this is what I need. Thanks